# Color not rendering from props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, tailwind-css, react-props

So, I'm passing in props to my JSX component, and then setting that props into a gradient from black to that prop. But whenever I try this, the gradient ends up going from black to just a transparent background.

```js
import React from 'react'

import Color from './color'

const App = () => {
    return (
        <div className="h-screen w-screen">
            <Color color="red-400" />
        </div>
    )
}

export default App
```

```js
import React from 'react'

const color = props => {


    return (
        <div className="h-screen w-screen">
            <div className={`h-full w-full absolute bg-gradient-to-r from-cyan-500 to-${props.color}`}>
                {props.text}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default color
```

What should I do?

Comment: Do you have any [colour customisation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/customizing-colors#using-the-default-colors) in your Tailwind config? Perhaps you haven't included cyan

Comment: Ive tried all different kinds of colors, including things like just red-500. And if i just set the color there to something like cyan it renders fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tailwind statically scans your files. It cannot interpolate strings. So whenever you pass a class, you have the pass the whole thing. `'to-red-500'` instead of `` `to-${'red-500'}` ``

Following changes should make it work(should probably update the prop name from `color` to say `tocolor`):

```js
import React from 'react'

import Color from './color'

const App = () => {
    return (
        <div className="h-screen w-screen">
            <Color color="to-red-400" />
        </div>
    )
}

export default App
```

```js
import React from 'react'

const color = props => {


    return (
        <div className="h-screen w-screen">
            <div className={`h-full w-full absolute bg-gradient-to-r from-cyan-500 ${props.color}`}>
                {props.text}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default color
```